# Acute accents not recognized + Error when requesting hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript, html, hyperlink, html-parsing

I'm building a Spanish dictionary. I get the definitions from www.rae.es . There are two issues at the time:

- the search engine doesn't work with acute accents ( á é í ó ú ). The output is an error message from rae.es stating that the word is not recognized. For example: for the word "baúl", this comes up (translated): "The word baÃºl isn't registered in the dictionary."
- the other problem is that whenever a word has 2 or more meanings a suggestion shows up with several options (these made by the dictionary) but if you click on one, an error comes up. The same happens if within a definition there is a hyperlink to another word.

click here to see an example: http://verbum.xtrweb.com/verbumpost.php?word=cuarto&word0=

You can also peek on the code by right clicking and then "inspect element" on chrome, and I think firefox and Safari too, to check how i retrieve the definitions. It's better if you use Google Chrome.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have to URL-encode your querystring. For example, replacing `ú` with `%FA` works: http://verbum.xtrweb.com/verbumpost.php?word=ba%FAl&word0=.

Also, the fact that error message says `baÃºl` indicates that at some point you're mixing encodings (probably UTF8 and Latin 1).

In JavaScript you can use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to encode a full URL, or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode part of a querystring.

Comment: rawurlencode() is the function I should use in PHP, but how can i implemented with these example? Please inspect element (right click in Chrome) to see the code.

Comment: I updated the answer with links to the related JavaScript functions. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Real Academia Española for information on the use of their content via search forms on other sites. You can ask them for the technical specifications, if they will grant you the right to such use (cf. to their [copyright statement](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000001.nsf/voTodosporId/4F34A4D521080642C12576C5003D16DE?OpenDocument)).